# Codeigniter mysql update return double row

Tags: codeigniter

I have prblem, am working in Codeigniter framework PHP and when i want update record in database after succes update he make new empty row...

I have page manager and list all pages.

### ID     Name    Delete   Edit

1      Home    delete   edit

When i click on "edit" and edit Home in "Test" and submit he return this result

### ID     Name    Delete   Edit

1      Home    delete   edit

2      0       delete   edit

Its inserting new row with 0 name value;

This is my model

```
public function edit_page($id = NULL)
    {
        $data = array (
            'name' => $this->input->post('page_name'),
            'body' => $this->input->post('page_body')
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('page', $data);
    }
```

Conroller

```
public function edit_page($id = NULL)
    {
            if($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
            {
                $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

                if($id != NULL)
                {
                   $this->load->model("page_m");
                   $this->page_m->edit_page($id);
                   $this->template->set_theme('zend') ->set_layout('admin.html')->build('edit', $this->data);
                }                                         
            }
    }
```

My view

```
<div class="grid-17">

    <div class="widget widget-plain">
        <form class="form uniformForm" action="<?php echo site_url('page/save_page');?>" method="POST">
            <div class="field-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <label> Naziv Strane </label>
                    <input type="text" name="page_name" id="fname" size="50" class="" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Body </label>
                <div id="section1">
                    <textarea cols="80" id="taBody" name="page_body" class="ckeditor" rows="10" runat="server"></textarea>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="box plain">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large dashboard_add" value="Sacuvaj">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</div> <!-- .grid -->
```

Comment: In your model the **$id** is being NULL
chek out that it should not b NULL

Comment: Your controller method is called `edit_page`and expects $id as a uri segment, whereas your form's html sets the action to a method called `save_page`, which does not have a 3rd uri-segment (the $id).

Comment: I remove Id Null and again he insert new row with 0 value name

Comment: The 3rd uri-segment ($id) is not set in your form's action url.

Comment: @Mudshark  i edite form action for second to test that and forget to back.

Comment: @Ivan check out my answer below.

Comment: Ty Mudshark i fix now. I change method paramter in $id=0. I remove NULL value.. Now is work.

Comment: @Ivan if my answer helped in solving your problem, please consider marking it as such :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form's action needs to have the $id as its third uri-segment:

```
<?php echo site_url('page/edit_page/'.$this->uri->segment(3));?>
```

Comment: I see that and put that. I forgot for form action

Comment: Work i forgot to set segment